# How can I call a method when the "url" property of the Windows Form's web browser changes?

Tags: c#, winforms, oauth-2.0, webbrowser-control, inotifypropertychanged

The web browser being [System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx).

So I know I can run code constantly to check if it has changed but this seems very inefficient. I have looked into INotifyPropertyChanged but don't know how I would implement it and am not sure it would work with a predefined system property. I have also looked into [Fody/PropertyChanged](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) but I don't believe it would inject into System properties. Any help is appreciated. Thanks so much.

Additionally, here is the reason I need this. I am using the web browser to do OAuth 2.0 authorization. I want to be able to read the url only when it changes to then get the auth token. Thanks again.

Comment: I would think that you should be able to simply handle the `Navigated` event.

Comment: That doesn't work in scenarios where Ajax is being used to modify the URL property and the contents of the webpage without actually causing navigation.   If you aren't in that scenario however, then use the Navigated event.